# Insert into select

Tags: sql

I want to insert data from `admission` into `student`.

```
INSERT INTO student(name,age) SELECT name, age from admission
```

But now I need to add 2 more fields to `student`: `username` and `pasword` at the same time I am selecting data from `admission`

Example:

```
INSERT INTO student(name,age,username, password)
  SELECT name, age
    FROM admission.....
```

How can i do this?

Comment: where are the values of `username` and `password` come from?

Comment: i see some helpful answers here... why not accept one of them?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where are the values of `username` and `password` come from but you can create a **virtual column (*with default value*)** so to match the number of columns in your `INSERT INTO`. Example,

```
INSERT INTO student(name,age,[username], [password]) 
SELECT name, age, 'userHere' as [username], 'passHere' as [password]
from admission.....
```

Comment: but table admission don't have field username and password.i want add more field to table student.Thank

Comment: i know that the columns may not exist as you have said but i'm asking where do the values  of `username` and `password` come from? as you can see above, you can change the `userHere` and `passwordHere` to something like `default value.

Answer (score 1):

The query you wrote:

```
INSERT 
  INTO student(name,age) 
  SELECT name, age from admission
```

is correct.
The rows of the `SELECT` and `INSERT` have to match.

However, I have no idea where the `username` and `password` fields come from. 
If they are in the same `admission` table, then, @john Woo's answer is correct.
If the table doesn't contain those values, then
you could use,

```
update Student set username=
(select username from <table> and <condition>)
where <condition>
```

The `<table>` is the table containing `username` field.

`<condition>` depends on how you identify the rows

or probably `join` the two tables i.e `admissions` and the other table containing `username` and `password` and complete the `insert` operation in a single query

```
INSERT 
  INTO student(name,age,username,password) 
    SELECT a.name, a.age, b.username, b.password
      FROM admission a
      JOIN <table> b ON a.username = b.username
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

if both new fields are nullable, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO student(name,age,username, password)
SELECT name, age, null, null 
FROM admission
```